# What will happen if SQLAlchemy attempts to create a row with a PK that is UUID based, and that PK already exists?

Tags: sqlalchemy

If I am using the following code...

```
import uuid
Column(Text(), default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex[:6], primary_key=True)
```

...and the new row being created just happens to have the same 6 digit UUID as an existing one, what will happen? Is there a way to catch it and have a go at creating another UUID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely an `IntegrityError` exception will be raised. You can do try-except blocks or do some tricks with the `do_execute` event, but the easiest way to make this a non-issue is to setup the UUID generation on the server side as a column default value.

Comment: I did end up setting it up on the server side, with a function in PostgreSQL. The column definition I used with SQLAlchemy is something like `id = Column(Text, primary_key=True, server_default=expression.text("my_uuid_function()"))`